# How can I solve this in nextjs " Can't find module "./lib/revalidate" "

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How can I solve this in nextjs : Can't find module "./lib/revalidate"

I already reinstall all node modules and also tried by installing revalidate. But it didn't work.
Please help me for this.I am stuck for a long time.

Comment: Can you show the block of code where you import revalidate? Please also share your package.json dependencies?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.